# Pomagranate mead sour

Tags: fermentation, taste, sour

I've been working on a pomagranate mead that has been fermenting for 3 weeks. I just racked it for the first time today and I tried a some, it was super sour... anyone know if this is normal and if it will go away and have the original pomagranate taste back. Also what might of caused this, did my pomagranate mead go bad or something

Comment: Can you describe the recipe and the process you followed?

Comment: Yeah I used 16 oz of pomagranate juice, 2 lbs honey,2/3 tsp Acid Blend,  yeast nutrient, 1/3 tsp Pectic Enzyme, 1/3 tsp Grape Tannin, and 1 campden tablet for first racking, cote de Blanc Wine Yeast... you boil honey at 180 for 10 min, let cool and add everything else.. rack after 3 weeks

Answer (score 2):

I can think of two reasons why your mead is sour:

1. [Pomegranate juice is sour](http://www.foodscience.caes.uga.edu/extension/documents/fdaapproximatephoffoodslacf-phs.pdf), with a pH of around 3.0. Assuming you've made 1 gallon batch, 16oz of pomegranate juice is enough to be noticeably tart. 16 oz of a pH 3.0 liquid diluted to 1 gallon [yields a pH](http://rechneronline.de/chemie-rechner/ph-dilution.php) of around 3.9 which, without any sugar to balance the acid, would taste quite sour.
2. Your mead was infected by acetobacter while fermenting. There's a group of bacteria called acetobacter that produce acid. They are responsible for sour pickles, sauerkraut, and vinegar. If this is the case, your mead would have a vinegar smell and taste.

My bet is that you don't have an infection; it's just the natural sourness of the pomegranate juice.

Comment: Alright is there anyway to reverse this, just as sugar?

Comment: If you add sugar, it will just ferment. Check this site for advice on back-sweetening cider. Most of those posts apply to your situation as well. The simplest thing to do is make syrup from water and honey. Add a bit of the syrup to a glass of mead.

Comment: You can cold stabilize and some of the tartness can drop out in the form of crystalline precipitation.